# Visual Designer errors, when there are no errors

Tags: visual-studio, custom-controls, designer

I get errors when viewing forms and there are not any.  I can close VS and reopen and it is fine.  What cases this?  Can it be fixed without closing?

Comment: which version of VS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify none of your custom user controls has any code errors.

Also try starting up Visual Studios using **devenv /resetskippkgs** from the command prompt.
It will reset packages if there is an error in loading.